# Visual Studio running on Eee 1215B E350 or C50

Tags: visual-studio, eeepc

I'm planning to buy a netbook, the ASUS Eee 1215B with E350 or C50 processor. My question is, is it capable of running Visual Studio 2005/2010/2008 and MSSQL Express at the same time?

Comment: It will, but how bad it performs will depend on how much RAM is in the unit.

Comment: Hm, so I should be concerned about the memory then. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes! I bought it... It works great...